# Can Camel run Esper with parallelProcessing?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-camel, esper

I have recently started using Camel with Esper. I know from the documentation that some Camel patterns, like Multicast, for example, can be run using the `parallelProcessing` method, which creates a pool of 10 threads to run that pattern by default.

After reading the [camel / esper page](http://camel.apache.org/esper.html) I did not see anything about using Esper in Camel with parallelProcessing.

My question is, can I run Esper in Camel using some sort of parallel processing? If yes how?

Comment: The [async](http://camel.apache.org/async.html) API should help you do that.

Comment: In theory, yes,  `.multicast().parallelProcessing().to("esper:abc", "esper:def", "esper.ghi")` should work (with a relevant AggregationStrategy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Multicast` is kind of different problem solver. It belongs only to ongoing flow. It just means that message from that point will be propagated to other components unchanged and in parallel behavior. Opposite is `Pipeline` component.

I think, what do you want is a [`seda`](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html) component. Opposite to `seda` is [`direct`](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) component. If you send a message to `direct` it will flow trough and start another flow only when the first ends. If you send a message to `seda` it will start a new flow every time it receive a message. You can define flow/thread pool and some other parameters how to behave.

So your camel config would look like this:

```
from("esper:xxx").to("seda:process");
```

Comment: Do you know of any example using this? It would be real nice if I could get my hands on one. Anyway, kudos++ !

Comment: Unfortunately no simple example... Just keep playing with it and I'm pretty sure you will get it soon. :)